# Simple shopping cart : calculating total price (logic)

Tags: c#, logic, shopping-cart

I have two DropDownlists for Category and Product, and two Label Controls for Price and SubTotal and then a TextBox control for the Quantity. So when i select the Category, the other DropDownlist Product will add some Products depending on that Category and when we select the Product, the Label (Price and SubTotal) and TextBox (Qunatity) will get the values depending on the Product. And when we change the Quantity, The SubTotal will be changed depending on the value of Quantity.

Problem with below method

```
protected void CalculateTotal()
{
    string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from cart", conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    lblsubtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
    conn.Close()
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: in your code you missed `total` variable

Comment: @Grundy can you rewrite this method and show me ?

Comment: how you want calc total?

Comment: @Grundy subtotal = quantity * price of each

Comment: so you need list subtotals? or one value total?

Comment: you need agreegate here : "``select sum(quantity * price) from cart``

Comment: so, see @EhsanSajjad comment

Comment: what you mean by that @Neha your question is not clear enough

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - I'm not able to get the logic of CalculateTotal method. It shows error. Can you write exact and complete code  for this method(CalculateTotal) ?

Comment: I know logic is simple quantity*price but i don't know the complete syntax.

Comment: @Neha i dont know your table structure what columns you have in table so how can i sort it?

Comment: @Neha, if you have a errors you need provide errors messages

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one value from query you can use [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
protected void CalculateTotal()
{
    string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select sum (quantity * price) from cart", conn);

    lblsubtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
    conn.Close()
}
```